# Add relative location RelativeLayout.BELOW

Tags: android, kotlin

I've the below code, in which I construct a "card" and adding to it both `Switch` and `button`, I need the `button` to be exactly under the switch, how to make it!

```
val swithy = Switch(this).apply {
    text = "active"
    isChecked = true
    id = View.generateViewId()
}

val mcard = CardView(this).apply {
    background = getDrawable(R.drawable.card_background)
    radius = 12F
    setContentPadding(25, 25, 25, 25)
    setCardBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY)
    cardElevation = 8F
    maxCardElevation = 12F
    addView(swithy, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
        RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM
        RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT
    })
    addView(Button(this.context).apply {
        text = "click me"
    }, LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
     /*     addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, swithy.id);  */
   // How to make this?!  it works in Java, how to make it in Kotlin
    })
}
```

`card_background.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:name="custom_view"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#c2f2f2f2" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF"
        />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using the below:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ELEMENT.id)
            }
```

Below is a full running code with me:

```
    val card1 = Switchy(this).apply {
        id = ConstraintLayout.generateViewId()
    }

    val card2 = Cardy(this).apply {
        id = ConstraintLayout.generateViewId()
    }

    main_layout.addView(card1)
    main_layout.addView(card2,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, card1.id)
            })

    main_layout.addView(Settings(this),
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, card2.id)
            }
    )
```

Where `Switchy` is:

```
class Switchy : RelativeLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        val colorOn = -0xcdc1ba

        val trackStates = ColorStateList(
                arrayOf(intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked), intArrayOf()),
                intArrayOf(Color.LTGRAY, colorOn)
        )

        this.apply {
            layoutParams = android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

            addView(Switch(context).apply {
                    background =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.card)
                    text = "active or not is it  ?"
                    isChecked = true
                    showText = true
                    textOn = "Active"
                    textOff = "Not Active"
                    trackTintList = trackStates
                    thumbTintList = trackStates
                }, LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT))
        }
    }
}
```

And `Cardy` is:

```
class Cardy : ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {

        val r = resources
        val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200f,
                r.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val myEditText = EditText(context).apply {
            id = ConstraintLayout.generateViewId()
            width = px
        }

        val myImageButton = ImageButton(context).apply({
            background = null
            setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_save_black_24px))
        })
        val myButton = Button(context).apply {
            text = "Press Me"
            setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            id = ConstraintLayout.generateViewId()
        }

        this.apply {
             layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
             background =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.card)
            addView(myEditText)
           // addView(myButton)
            addView(myImageButton)

        }

        val set = ConstraintSet().apply {
            constrainHeight(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
            constrainWidth(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)

            constrainHeight(myImageButton.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
            constrainWidth(myImageButton.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)

            connect(myImageButton.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0)
        }
        set.applyTo(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to manage my requirements using `ConstraintLayout`, I'm posting my answer here, may some people find it helpful:

In `MainActivity.kt` I'm calling my custom element as:

```
main_layout.addView(Cardy(this))
```

My custom element `Cardy.kt` is:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.widget.Button
import oryx.kortex.locateme.R
import android.graphics.Color
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet
import android.widget.EditText
import android.util.TypedValue

class Cardy : ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {

        val r = resources
        val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200f,
                r.displayMetrics).toInt()
        val myEditText = EditText(context).apply {
            id = ConstraintLayout.generateViewId()
            width = px
        }
        val myButton = Button(context).apply {
            text = "Press Me"
            setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)
            id = ConstraintLayout.generateViewId()
        }

        this.apply {
                    layoutParams = LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
                    background =  ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.card)
                    addView(myButton)
                    addView(myEditText)
        }

        val set = ConstraintSet().apply {
            constrainHeight(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
            constrainWidth(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
            connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0)
            connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0)
            connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
            connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)

            constrainHeight(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
            constrainWidth(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)

            connect(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0)
            connect(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0)
            connect(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    myButton.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 70)

        }

        set.applyTo(this)

    }
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

**NOTES**:

This part is to center the element `horizontal`:

```
   connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0)
   connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
                    ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0)
```

This part is to center the element `vertically`:

```
connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.TOP,
        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0)
connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
        ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0)
```

To have both elements in the same line, below code do the job:

```
val set = ConstraintSet().apply {
    constrainHeight(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
    constrainWidth(myEditText.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)

    constrainHeight(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)
    constrainWidth(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)

    connect(myButton.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,
            ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout also could be an option, below code set a an `EditText` with `ImageButton`:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView
import android.widget.*

import android.widget.LinearLayout

class RespondTo : CardView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {


        val parent = LinearLayout(context)

        parent.apply {
            layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f).apply {
                orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL

                addView(EditText(context).apply {
                    id = generateViewId()
                    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.9f).apply {
                    }
                })
                addView(ImageButton(context).apply({
                    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f)
                    background = null
                    setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_save_black_24px))
                    id = generateViewId()
                    layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
                        addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT)
                        // addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, myImageButton.id)
                    }
                }))
            }
        }
        this.addView(parent)
    }
}
```